# finding the sum of $f(k)=\sum_{n=1}^k a*n^{log(n)}$

Tags: summation

I am trying to find the sum of: $$f(k)=\sum_{n=1}^k a*n^{log(n)}$$

Would appreciate help,

Thanks!

Comment: $$
\sum_{i=1}^n a n^{\log{n}} = n a n^{\log{n}}
$$

Comment: Sorry, mis-wrote what I was looking for. Fixed the original post